# Grunt plugin: responsive_images - files sie are too large

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-plugins

I'm using https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images for image resisting. But the outcome fillies size is too big. For example the original file size is 277KB with dimensions 2880x1800, and the resided file has size of **533KB** with dimensions 1000x625.

These are the settings of the plugin:

```
 photo: {
                options: {
                    engine: 'im',
                    sizes: [{
                        name: '1000',
                        width: 1000,
                    }]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/assets/images/posts',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}', '!**/*-{600,900,1200}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}'],
                    dest: '<%= config.app %>/assets/images/posts'
                }]
```

Can somebody explain why is this happening, and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Your image is jpeg? you can use the quality option of this plugin. Set is with 7 or 8. Maybe it works.

Comment: I've tried and it's the same, because the default value is the max one posible

Comment: @Mario Alejandro Araque you are right.
By default the plugin doesn't compress the fils, I had not read the documentation properly. 

Thank you!